# Change default color of grid header in Ext JS classic theme

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I want to change the default color of grid panel header. By searching on Google I found a fiddle changing the color of the grid header but in the classic theme it is not working.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/v8j&view/editor

I changed the theme from drop down in the fiddle the color disappear. Is there any way to change the color of grid panel header in the classic theme?

Answer (score 1):

The classic theme contains images for grid headers. Add `background-image: none;` to your css override.

Here is the updated fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2fd6&view/editor

Comment: can I change the all header to white by just one cls on the grid panel?
Now I have to put the cls on every column header.

Comment: I just want to change the color of one specific grid header not all. this will change all grid headers in the application

Comment: You can give the grid panel a specific css class with the cls config like this: `cls: 'grid-panel-class'`. Then you can set your custom css like `.grid-panel-class .x-column-header {}` and `.grid-panel-class .x-column-header.red {}`

Answer (score 0):

Assign a cls property to grid say grid-cls and write below snippet in your CSS file. This will change background of all headers to red.

```
.grid-cls .x-column-header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

For changing color of specific column header give cls to that specific column say test and add below snippet in your code.

```
.x-column-header.test{
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: I just want to change color of one specific grid header not all. 
this will change the all grid headers in the application

Comment: Your question dint specified that, anyways updated the answer.I hope this helps.